# Android размер контрола в процентах

Tags: android, вёрстка, activity, android-fragment, style

Насколько я знаю в андроид нет возможности задавать размер контролов в процентах. 
В html+css это возможно и это очень удобно. Теперь вопрос. Допустим у меня есть активити на которой я отображаю два фрагмента. На первом отображается какой-то контент а на втором две кнопкпи ОК и Cancel.  Оба фрагмента должны занимать весь экран по ширине, а по высоте распределение должно быть таким: первый фрагмент 90% высоты экрана, а второй - оставшиеся 10%.

В html+css это можно сделать [так](http://jsfiddle.net/49wykz94/)
А как добиться этого в Android?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используй атрибуты android:layout_weight в XML разметке, она позволит указать в каких пропорциях распределять место двух компонентов. Например:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      android:orientation="horizontal"> 
  <Button 
      android:id="@+id/button1" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:text="B1" 
      android:layout_weight="1"> 
  </Button> 
  <Button 
      android:id="@+id/button2" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:text="B2" 
      android:layout_weight="3"> 
  </Button> 
  <Button 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:id="@+id/button3" 
      android:text="B3" 
      android:layout_weight="2"> 
  </Button> 
</LinearLayout>
```

В данном примере три кнопки получат соответственно 1/6, 3/6 и 2/6 общего места
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для твоей ситуации попробуй такую разметку:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:name="android.support.v4.app.ListFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="OK"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Отмена"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Спасибо. А как сделать распределение размеров для высот контролов?

Comment: Смысл тот же, в данном случае в LinearLayout нужно указать android:orientation="vertical". Button'ы я взял чтобы пример был нагляднее, вы же можете применить этот атрибут для любых компонентов. В вашем случае советовал бы две нижние кнопки запихнуть в отдельный горизонтальный LinearLayout, и уже ему в целом указать вес = 1, в то время как верхнему фрагменту вес = 9